# Animate route change in react-router-dom switch component

Tags: animation, react-router, react-transition-group

I'm having a really hard time animating the transition from one page to another with `react-router-dom`. [The exmaple](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions) is fine but I can't get it to work within a `Switch` component provided by `react-router-dom`.

I've tried doing this around the `Switch` component or inside it but it doesn't do anything (also no warnings or errors in the console).

**Example**

```
class Layout extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { account } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="MAIN">
                <Header image={account.resources.logo} backgroundColor={account.theme} />
                <ProgressionBar />

                <div className="MAIN__content">
                    <CSSTransition classNames="fade" timeout={{ enter: 1500, exit: 500 }}>
                        <Switch key={this.props.location.key} location={this.props.location}>
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}start`} component={Start} />
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}questions`} component={Questions} />
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}comments`} component={Comments} />
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}capture`} component={Capture} />
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}disclaimer`} component={Disclaimer} />
                            <Route exact path={`${basePath}finish`} component={null} />
                        </Switch>
                    </CSSTransition>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.fade-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-exit.fade-exit-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Melounek for the help, the issue resided in that I needed to wrap the `CSSTransition` in a `TransitionGroup` as shown in the migration docs of `react-transition-group`.

**Example**

```
class Layout extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { account, location } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="MAIN">
                <Header image={account.resources.logo} backgroundColor={account.theme} />
                <ProgressionBar />

                <div className="MAIN__content">
                    <TransitionGroup>
                        <CSSTransition
                            key={location.key}
                            classNames="fade"
                            timeout={{ enter: 1000, exit: 1000 }}
                            transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
                            transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
                        >
                            <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}start`} component={Start} />
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}questions`} component={Questions} />
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}comments`} component={Comments} />
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}capture`} component={Capture} />
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}disclaimer`} component={Disclaimer} />
                                <Route exact path={`${basePath}finish`} component={null} />
                            </Switch>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<CSSTransition classNames="test" transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
  <Switch key={this.props.location.pathname} location={this.props.location}>
    ...
  </Switch>
</CSSTransition>
```

Comment: Still no effect :( See updated answer for how you suggested.Could it be because this is not at the `BrowserHistory` level?

Answer (score 0):

try to rename `classNames` to `transitionName`.

and the css `.fade-exit` also should be `.fade-leave` if you are using these libraries: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html or not?

Comment: They depreciated that library, it moved to `react-transition-group` which you find [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)

Comment: Also the [comments here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4351#issuecomment-281196606) did not really help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <CSSTransition key={this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[1]} timeout={500} classNames="fadeTranslate" mountOnEnter={true} unmountOnExit={true}>
    <div className="WRAPPER">
        <Switch location={this.props.location}>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
            <Route path="/albumn" component={Albumn} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</CSSTransition>
```

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5279#issuecomment-315652492